# NodeJS: Improve SFTP server performance

Tags: node.js, express, ssh2-sftp

I am trying to render images and PDF files from a SFTP server using [ssh2-sftp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client) module, but it is very slow and I am wondering if there is any way to improve the performance of requests. For a file about 168 KB it takes more than 1.5s so it's really really slow.

My current observations of performance issues are:

- Currently I'm creating every time a connection
- The server I'm using is small (Azure Standard B1s (1 vcpu, 1 GiB memory))

```js
const ssh2_sftp = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const router = require('express').Router();
const sftp = new ssh2_sftp();
const FileType = require('file-type');

const sftp_config = {...};
const public_path = /^\/files\/public/

router.get(/^\/image/, async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.image)
        return res.status(422).end();
    if (!public_path.test(req.query.image))
        return res.status(403).end();

    let file;
    try {
        await sftp.connect(sftp_config);
        file = await sftp.get(req.query.image);
    } catch (err) {
        if(err.toString().includes('No such file'))
            return res.status(404).end();
        return res.status(502).end();
    } finally {
        sftp.end();
    }
    let file_info = await FileType.fromBuffer(file);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', file_info.mime);
    res.status(200).end(file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have doubts in the way I send the image to the client with express, something in me says that it is not the correct way. And also I'm trying to create some pool but I can't find a proper solution or at least a singleton design, but I'm afraid to receive too many requests.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: DId you try fastGet ? [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#fastgetremotepath-localpath-options--string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#fastgetremotepath-localpath-options--string). Maybe it would faster if we will not send the file directly using buffer.

Comment: fastGet it's intended for download remotely, but I'm rendering the image on the client. Am I confused about how does rendering work?